# Xlwings - adding columns

Tags: excel, python-3.x, xlwings

I am using xlwings and am trying to sum two cells, A1 + B1, and have the output entered into a third cell C1.  I want to to do this for a range (A1->A9) + (B1->B9) and have them written to cells (C1->C9).  My current command is  Range('C3').value = [sum(x) for x in zip(Range('A3:A9').value, Range('B3:B9').value)] This sums the values correctly but the answers are written out horizontally to cells C3-I3.  I know that the command  Range('A1').value = [[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]] would list the elements of a list vertically but I am not sure  how to incorporate this into my command.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making this easier is an open [issue](https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/11). For simple lists, you can do the following (note that on Python 2, you don't need `list` around `zip`:

```
Range('C3').value = list(zip([sum(x) for x in zip(Range('A3:A9').value,
                              Range('B3:B9').value)]))
```

If you have `numpy` installed, the same can be achieved like that:

```
import numpy as np
Range('C3').value = (Range('A3:A9', asarray=True).value + 
                     Range('B3:B9', asarray=True).value)[:,np.newaxis]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
import xlwings as xw
sht = xw.Book().sheets[0]
sht.range('C3').options(transpose=True).value \
=[sum(x) for x in zip(sht.range('A3:A9').value, sht.range('B3:B9').value)]
```

Answer (score 0):

To make values print out in Excel vertically you simply need to covert them in lists, to get list of lists finally, just as you described.

```
from xlwings import Workbook, Range
wb = Workbook('example.xlsx')
a_col = Range('A1').vertical.value # or Range('A1:A9').value if you wish
b_col = Range('B1').vertical.value
c_col = zip(a_col, b_col)
c_col = [[sum(x)] for x in c_col]  # use '[]' here inside of list constructor
Range('C1').value = c_col
wb.close()
```